Testing Push Notifications on device with .apns file
Ok the iOS Simulator you can drop an .apns file and the device receives a push motivation.
Is it possible to replicate this on a real device with the .apns file? Could we drag and drop the file using Apple Configurator app or Devices window from Xcode?

how about push notification console?

Thx for mentioning the .apns file, I worked on a Push notification implementation last year, and I don't think Apple mentions it in their docs.
I'm reasonably sure you need to do a proper build configured for APNS, because APNS deeply tied into the OS (and signed relationships between the APNS, iOS and your app).
